# printout 2 dimensions array that have different row length by columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can you print the first column then second column if the columns
existed so basically `arr[0][0]` to `arr[0 to 7][0]` then
`arr[0,2,3,5][1]` then `arr[2,5][2]` then `arr[2][3]`
but in  dynamic way as the length in every execution will be different

```
String[][] arr = new String [7][];

arr[0]=new String[2];   
arr[1]=new String[1];   
arr[2]=new String[4];   
arr[3]=new String[2];   
arr[4]=new String[1];   
arr[5]=new String[3];   
arr[6]=new String[1];   
arr[7]=new String[1];
```

Comment: Please post the code where you perform the printing.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: the code is on top a 2d array with variant row length print the array columns by column note that some column for certain rows will not be there as the rows are of different length

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to print? Columns which have the same length? Give some example.

Comment: HBC Digital
We have 5 open jobs ♥
Imagine yourself at HBC Digital
Learn more
up vote
-2
down vote
favorite
 

first column then second column if the columns
existed so basically arr[0][0] to arr[0 to 7][0] then
arr[0,2,3,5][1] then arr[2,5][2] then arr[2][3]
but in dynamic way as the length in every execution will be different

Comment: https://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void printByColumns(String[][] jaggedArray) {
    int maxColumns = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.length; i++) {
         maxColumns = Math.max(jaggedArray[i].length, maxColumns);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++) {
        String text = "";

        for(int j = 0; j < jaggedArray.length; j++) {
            if (i < jaggedArray[j].length) {
                text += String.format("%s\t", jaggedArray[j][i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you wanted. The code contains two methods which display jagged array row by row and column by column.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    private String[][] generateArray(int rows, int maxColumns) {
        String[][] array = new String[rows][];

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            int columns = (int) (Math.random() * maxColumns) + 1;

            String[] innerArray = new String[columns];
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                innerArray[j] = String.format("Row: %d Column: %d", i, j);
            }

            array[i] = innerArray;
        }

        return array;
    }

    private void printByRows(String[][] jaggedArray) {        
        for(int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.length; i++) {
            String rowText = "";

            for(int j = 0; j < jaggedArray[i].length; j++) {
                rowText += String.format("%s\t", jaggedArray[i][j]);
            }

            System.out.println(rowText);
        }
    }

    private void printByColumns(String[][] jaggedArray) {
        int maxColumns = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.length; i++) {
             maxColumns = Math.max(jaggedArray[i].length, maxColumns);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++) {
            String text = "";

            for(int j = 0; j < jaggedArray.length; j++) {
                if (i < jaggedArray[j].length) {
                    text += String.format("%s\t", jaggedArray[j][i]);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String[][] array = generateArray(8, 5);
        System.out.println("Array row by row");
        printByRows(array);

        System.out.println("Array column by column");
        printByColumns(array);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        new JavaApplication1().run();
    }
}
```